# hardening a server: disallow password-login for sudoers and log unusual ips

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, security, debian, sudo

Two question regarding sudo-login into an ubuntu-system (debian tips welcome as well):

- Is it possible to require sudoers on my box to only login with publickey-authentication?
- Is it possible to log which ip sudoers log in from and check that for "unusual activity" or take actions? I'm thinking about temporarily removing sudo-rights if sudoers don't log in from whitelisted IPs. Or is that too risky to be exploited?

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: Oh, Sry. Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: Your question seems to be confusing `sudo` with `ssh`. I think you meant `ssh` in all of those cases. And `ssh` allows one to do all of those.

Comment: No, i meant sudoers, since it's those accounts that shouldn't be compromised. I'm unfortunately in a situation where i have boxes with 30 users, 5 of them sudoers and i don't trust every one of them to know what they're doing.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to the first question here: https://serverfault.com/questions/238711/force-ssh-public-key-authentication-for-specific-users. Just add the following to sshd_config:

```
Match Group sudoers
PasswordAuthentication no
```